# A conjectured formula for the polylogarithm of a negative integer order

Tags: binomial-coefficients, conjectures, polylogarithm

I discovered the following formula while working on the sequence [A141697](https://oeis.org/A141697) from the OEIS. I have no idea whether it is something trivial or not. *I would be very happy to know more about it.*

$$
\textrm{Li}_\nu\left(z\right)=
 \frac
   {
   6 (1+z)^{-\nu-1} +  \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{-\nu-1}
       \displaystyle\left( -6 \displaystyle{{-\nu-1}\displaystyle\choose k}+7\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}(-1)^j (k-j+1)^{-\nu} {{-\nu+1}\
\choose j} \right) z^k
   }
   {
   7 (1 - z)^{-\nu+1}
   }z
$$
when $\nu$ is a negative integer.

In case I mistyped the formula, here are my codes in two different languages:

For Pari-GP:

```
mypolylog(n, x) = { ( 6*(x+1)^(-n-1)
   + sum(k=0,-n-1, (-6*binomial(-n-1,k)
       + 7*sum(j=0,k+1, (-1)^j * (k-j+1)^(-n) * binomial(-n+1,j)))*x^k) ) * x
    / (7*(1-x)^(-n+1) ) }
```

For Mathematica:

```
mypolylog[n_, x_] :=  (6*(x+1)^(-n-1)
    + Sum[(x^k*(-6*Binomial[-n-1, k]
        + 7*Sum[(-1)^j*(k-j+1)^(-n)*Binomial[-n+1, j], {j, 0, k+1}])),
    {k, 0, -n-1}]) / ( 7*(1 - x)^(-n+1) ) * x
```

Comment: How do got the formula? Have you tried a reformulation of the rational functions using Stirling or Eulerian numbers given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values?

Comment: @gammatester I empirically discovered this formula by using a tool I wrote for discovering identities: https://github.com/baruchel/oeis which detected A141697(n)=3*A168524(n)-2*A154337(n). The formula above comes from that.

Comment: Nice work. You can use $6=t$ and $7=t+1$ where $t\neq -1$ in your formula instead.

Comment: This could similarly apply to A141696 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simplify formulas define $\, B(n,k) := {-n-1\choose k}, \,$
$\, A(n,k) := \sum_{j=0}^{k+1} (-1)^j (k-j+1)^{-n} {-n+1 \choose j}, \,$
and $\, u := 1-t \,$ where $\,n<0\,$ is a negative integer and $\, t\neq 0. \,$ Your formula is the $\, t=7 \,$ case of the lightly simplified equation

$$ \textrm{Li}_n(z) = \frac{z}t (1-z)^{n-1} (-u (1-z)^{-n+1} +
  u \sum_{k=0}^{-n-1} z^k B(n,k) + t \sum_{k=0}^{-n-1} z^k A(n,k) ). $$
But $\, (1-z)^{-n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{-n-1} z^k B(n,k) \,$ simplies it to
$ \textrm{Li}_n(z) = z (1-z)^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{-n-1} z^k A(n,k). \,$

The numbers in $\,A(-n,k-1)\,$ are the triangular [OEIS sequence  A008292](http://oeis.org/A008292) of Eulerian numbers which entry has the information "O.g.f. for n-th row: (1-x)^(n+1)*polylog(-n, x)/x".